# Using class objects in another class

Tags: c++, function, class

I am currently trying to create a simple game using OOP. Right now, I am trying to let the two players in the game each set a wager to win.

Here is what my player.cpp looks like currently -

```
Player::Player() : score(0), wallet(1000) { }

void Player::setWager() {
    std::cout << "Please enter your wager." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> wager;
    wallet -= wager;
}

int Player::getWallet() {
    return wallet;
}

int Player::getWager() {
    return wager;
}
```

For this, int wager, int wallet, and int score are stored within player.h/player.cpp.

Within main, I use the player constructor and then create the wagers like this -

```
int main() {
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    p1.setWager();
    p2.setWager();
}
```

Now, I also have a .h/.cpp file for the table the game will be played on. I want to be able to take the wagers formed for p1 and p2, and store them into an int named winWager in table.cpp, like (in pseudocode) -

```
void Table::setWinWager() {
    winWager = p1.wager + p2.wager;
}
```

Of course, int winWager is held within table.h. How can I take the wagers from p1 and p2 in main(or player?) and let them be used for table.cpp? I am new to OOP, so this has been confusing. I am using C++. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's your call to `getWager()`, I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher getWager() only produces the single wager per player object. I am trying to take the single wagers from each player object and then put them into an integer within table.cpp that is the sum of both player wagers.

Comment: `winWager = p1.getWager() + p2.getWager();` But what's your problem?? Using an include header?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher It says it is not declared in the scope when I attempt to compile, and I am adding "player.h".

Comment: Then pass them by reference (make them const, and make the getters const as well).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have basically two choices

You could pass the players as parameters to your setWinWager method

```
void Table::setWinWager(const Player& p1, const Player& p2) {
    winWager = p1.wager + p2.wager;
}
```

Or you could have your Table object have two players as members, presumably passed in via it's constructor.

```
class Table
{
public:
    Table(const Player& p1, const Player& p2); 
    void setWinWager();
private:
    Player p1;
    Player p2;
    int winwager;
};
```

Which is correct? That depends on what your Table object represents which is really only a question you can answer.